# Which Java UI framework provides Mac OSX 10.9 user experience on Windows 7/8?

Tags: java, windows, macos, user-experience

I would like to develop windows applications that has native Mac OSX 10.9 look and feel.  Is it possible?  In case no such framework is available, what alternatives are available?  Can I use any open source UI assets to achieve Mac look and feel?

Comment: Have you tried http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html ?

Comment: `I would like to develop windows applications that has native Mac OSX 10.9 look and feel` - wrong. Windows is not the Mac. You could argue the Mac is much better, which I have no arguments against, but most Windows users will find your applications really unfamiliar, and your applications will probably just "not fit" into the Windows desktop, in terms of look and feel.

Comment: BTW, if you're after `Windows` (specifically) applications, then forget java and use `C#`, which is way better.

Comment: *"Which Java UI framework provides Mac OSX 10.9 user experience on Windows 7/8?"*  Oh God forbid!  I love the look of OS X but use Windows because it works out cheaper for a complete HW/SW stack.  But I wouldn't want to see an inconsistent OS X looking GUI on Windows.  It would suck rocks!

Comment: That doesn't matter I guess, you don't know who will be using it, maybe mac users that are forced to use Windows?

Comment: @HighCore way better than Java... you might wanna reconsider: cross-platform issues, the same methods with longer names, not to mention the IDE you have to pay for. I am not the hater of non-Java languages, but comments like yours are genuinely funny :)

Comment: @lucas [Way better](http://www.slideshare.net/jeffz/why-java-sucks-and-c-rocks-final). and Visual Studio Express is Free. And if you don't like it there's SharpDevelop, which is free and open source. java sucks, face it. It doesn't even have properties. And you're waiting for 2014 to have a poor imitation of LINQ, which C# had by 2007. While C# 5 brought us `async / await`. And I said `Windows applications specifically`. Please...

Comment: @HighCore  *"Please... "*  Please take your 'language wars' elsewhere.

Comment: @HighCore I guess I'll stick with Java and you carry on with c# and I bet that world will be a better place

Comment: While using Mac look and feel might bring legal problems, I don't see why everyone is so eager to criticize instead of actually helping with his question.  

Also, don't mind HighCore, he's got a "language crusade" going on. Just ignore him every time his comments include the word "java".

Comment: Whoa!   So much hate in this world.   Now why have people started down voting the question? You want me to stop using StackOverflow?   Or,  is my personal preference for non-native ux so rude that you highly offended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to develop windows applications that has native Mac OSX 10.9 look and feel.

Use this instead:

```
try {
    // Significantly improves the look of the output in each OS..
    // By making it look 'just like' all the other apps.
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch(Exception weTried) {
}
```

Note:  It will **not** port the OS X look to Windows.  But your users will thank you for that.

> Can I use any open source UI assets to achieve Mac look and feel?

Nope.  Apple would sue the pants off anyone who tried to replicate their look.

Comment: -1. Don't presume to know what his users will think when you don't even know what he's trying to do. Also, doesn't answer the question in any meaningful way. Most of the time, when your answer consists of "Do something that doesn't do what you wanted, but does something I believe is better" you're probably not doing a very good job.

Comment: @Yandros  *"when you don't even know what he's trying to do"*  'forcing another OS' PLAF on the end user' is ***all*** I need to know.

Comment: Not really. It may be a port of an OSX application, and he wants to make sure the users aren't confused by the change in themes. Or a customer might have asked specifically for something with an OSX look and feel, for whatever reason (maybe they do most of their work in macs, and they don't want to distract their employees). There are many legitimate reasons for wanting to do something like that.

Comment: @Yandros "It may be a port of an OSX application,"*  Yes, I'm *familiar with them.*  I used to use one (didn't name it, because I can't quite recall what it was, but it had to do with QuickTime files).  ***It was f_cking horrendous.***  *"Or a customer might have asked specifically"*  The customer might have asked specifically for the program to execute the user on bad input.  Does not bloody justify it though.  *"There are many legitimate reasons for wanting to do something like that."*  **Every one of which** would have you sued by Apple!  Your talking complete nonsense.

Comment: You say I'm the one talking nonsense, but you're the one who thinks personal opinion is an appropiate answer to the scenarios; those are all legitimate reasons why a programmer would need to use an OSX theme instead of just using any nice one regardless of your opinion. And yes, it may lead to legal trouble, but that doesn't justify the fact that you decided to discard the actual question asked.

Comment: @Yandros  *"that doesn't justify the fact that you decided to discard the actual question asked"*  Sure it does.  See [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score -1):

Try using the method bellow. You won't be able to get a mac look and feel but there are a few you can try.  I prefer the system default look and feel.

> public static UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] getInstalledLookAndFeels()
>
> Returns an array of LookAndFeelInfos representing the LookAndFeel
>   implementations currently available. The LookAndFeelInfo objects can
>   be used by an application to construct a menu of look and feel options
>   for the user, or to determine which look and feel to set at startup
>   time. To avoid the penalty of creating numerous LookAndFeel objects,
>   LookAndFeelInfo maintains the class name of the LookAndFeel class, not
>   the actual LookAndFeel instance.
>
> The following example illustrates setting the current look and feel
>   from an instance of LookAndFeelInfo:
>
> UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());