# How can I transplant the OSX's LookAndFeel to other type of systems in Java

Tags: java, macos, look-and-feel

I Set the `LookAndFeel` to be `System`, And I found that it looks pretty in OSX system. Like this:

[image]

However, when I ran it on Windows, it changed to be fairly uncomfortable:

[image]

So I am wondering how can I transplant LookAndFeel and standardized it.

Comment: I'd just run with a system look and feel.

Also this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570598/which-java-ui-framework-provides-mac-osx-10-9-user-experience-on-windows-7-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know how to make it 100% same, but [SeaGlass](https://code.google.com/p/seaglass/) Look and Feel is the one I use and looks similar.

I hope it helps you, at least as a start point.